# Long Comments e Long Strings

Tags: lua

Gostaria de uma explicação apropriada sobre o que são *Long Comments* e *Long Strings*, apesar de que possam ser pequenos recursos.

Answer (score 2):

Long Comments (comentários longos) são comentários utilizando *Long Format*. Long Strings (strings longas) representam strings, mas também utilizando o Long Format.

### Long Format

Long Format (formato longo) é um formato que diferencia entre as versões -5.1 e +5.2.

[**Versão 5.1**](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.1)

Nessa versão o formato inicia com a sequência `[[` e termina com a sequência `]]` relacionada (os mesmos pares podem se repetir dentro).

[**Versão 5.2**](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.1)

Nessa versão o formato recebe um nível de fechadura. O formato apenas inicia se o seu início é válido. O início começa com `[` e conta os símbolos `=` até que apareça `]` para finalizar ele mesmo. Caso houve qualquer caractere fora `=` e `[` , então o formato não inicia.

O *nível de fechadura* será a quantia de assigns (`=`).

O *fim* do formato é semelhante ao início, só muda `[` para `]` e requere a mesma quantia de assigns.

### Long Comment

Nada especial sobre seu formato, além de que o formato deve ser declarado depois de `--`.

### Long String

O formato da string longa não interpreta o escape (`\`) , requere fim e tem duas ações de fundo:

- Converte a sequência de bytes `0D 0A` (carriage return e new line, \r\n) e o byte `0D` (\r) para `0A` (\n)
- Ignora a primeira quebra de linha (`0D 0A`, `0A` ou `0D`) seguida pelo seu início

O interpretador da linguagem assume que os bytes do código alvo são códigos de caracteres, por isso qualquer futuro problema se relaciona à codificação de seus caracteres.